# ARM Template deployment - The resource identificator is malformed

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy multiple LogicApps and other resources together from a single ARM Template. When i try to do a `Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` with the template that i created it throws this error

```
Code    : InvalidTemplate
Message : Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'MyLogicApp' at line '159' and column '9' is not valid: The resource identificator
          '/subscriptions/8a506831-cc80-4512-b51b-6ed4cc32b2cd/resourceGroups/arm/providers/Microsoft.Web/' is malformed. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage
          details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.
```

This is the block where the resource is created from my code.

[image]

I cannot seem to find any resource regarding this. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in the template you constructed resourceId poorly:

```
/subscriptions/8a506831-cc80-4512-b51b-6ed4cc32b2cd/resourceGroups/arm/providers/Microsoft.Web/
```

it should end with a resource name. hard to tell when you do not provide the template.

In this case one of the parameters passed to the template was empty, hence this error indicating that there is no name for the resource.

Comment: this is fine right `"id": "[concat(subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/',resourceGroup().location,'/managedApis/servicebus')]",`

Comment: eh, i'm unaware how this particular ID should be constructed, but usually, it should be `subscriptions/GUID/resourceGroups/name/providers/type/name` yours is `subscriptions/GUID/providers/type/random/subtype/name`

Comment: I had seperatetemplates for all logic apps , it isworking fine when deployed. But i have combined it now , i cannot seem to find the error . The construction of this line i provided is same on seperate as well as combined one

Comment: i wont be able to help without the full template. you have an error in the template.

Comment: Here's the template @4c74356b41 https://gist.github.com/hariharan618/887c3360d1318f6d5863e9df578c190b

Comment: i just looked through it and dont get any error. tried deploying it and it did pass validation. not sure are you trying the same version?

Comment: i get the same error while i do `Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` i am using vscode

Comment: I am getting same error in PowerShell ISE too https://imgur.com/a/SZ6I21G

Comment: are you passing an empty string to one of the parameters?

Comment: Thanks alot man, it seems some params were empty. Thanks alot

Comment: if you update the answer i can accept it and it will help others in future

Comment: thanks, did that, i'd appreciate an upvote as well ;)